# Unable to bundle install 'open-uri'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

I am very new to Rails. I am making a web application in which I am using nokogiri to search different websites to extract text from them. And so in the Gemfile, I have written require 'nokogiri' and 'open-uri', but when I bundle install I get this error :

```
Could not find gem 'open-uri (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine
```

But when I do require 'open-uri' in my console, it displays yes. 
So why can't I bundle install, or is there any alternative to it ?

Comment: We need to see a minimal example of your code that duplicates this. The [OpenURI class is part of Ruby's Standard Library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/index.html), so you don't have to install (or bundle) it, just `require` it.

Answer (score 18):

OpenUri is part of the Ruby standard library, you only need to require it if you want to use it in your code.  No gem is required.

Comment: I added require 'open-uri' in my code where I am using nokogiri, but still it's not working. I am doing this : <% @doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-25330366")) %>. But I get error : No such file or directory - http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-25330366. I assume this is because the url can't be opened.